# C#-Xml Serialization - Serializing the wrong format

Tags: c#, serialization

So, I have this Person class that I want to serialize (By the way, I'm very new to serialization):

```
[Serializable()]
public class Person : ISerializable
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "No name";
    public int Age { get; set; } = 5;
    public string Gender { get; set; } = "Female";
    public Person(string name, int age, string gender)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
        Gender = gender;
    }
    public Person() { }
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("Name", Name);
        info.AddValue("Gender", Gender);
    }
    public Person(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Name = (string)info.GetValue("Name", typeof(string));
        Gender = (string)info.GetValue("Gender", typeof(string));
    }
}
```

However, when I serialized it and opened the file that I serialized to, the file also contain the Age property's value. Even though, I didn't say "info.AddValue("Age", Age)" in the GetObjectData method. Here's the code I used for serialization, maybe there's something wrong with it:

```
Person person1 = new Person("Raksa", 13, "Male");

XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
using (Stream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\Testdat.txt", FileMode.Create))
{
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, person1);
}
```

So, what's the problem here? Technically, during serialization, it will serialize what I want to serialize that I defined in the GetObjecctData method (That's what microsoft said).

P.S. Thanks alot! Appreaciate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore Property to be (XML) serialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24178992/ignore-property-to-be-xml-serialized)

Answer (score 1):

`XmlSerializer` simply doesn't use `ISerializable` (or `[Serializable]` for that matter); it either uses `IXmlSerializable` (which I do **not** recommend doing), or it uses implicit or explicit shape information about the type. In your case, what you want is simply:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "No name";
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int Age { get; set; } = 5;
    public string Gender { get; set; } = "Female";
    public Person(string name, int age, string gender)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
        Gender = gender;
    }
    public Person() { }
}
```

The bits you need are:

- a `public` type
- with a `public` parameterless constructor
- public properties are serialized as eponymous elements by default *unless* they are marked `[XmlIgnore]`

There are a lot of other xml-influencing attributes you can use for finer control (attributes, xml-text, root-name, namespace, etc).

---

For completeness, note that `BinaryFormatter` uses `ISerializable`, but... you should probably avoid that in general.